# C++ TensorFlow: How to specify "axis" in "Mean"

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a simple feedforward neural network in C++ TensorFlow. I am not able to specify "axis" in "Mean" function of C++ tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/mean).

I am trying to implement following Python-TensorFlow line in C++ TensorFlow:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
```

Following is in C++ TensorFlow and this is what I am trying to make equivalent to above line (in Python TensorFlow)

```
auto cost = Mean(root.WithOpName("cost"), SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits(root, output_layer, y));
```

I am getting error something like "specify axis" and I have no idea that how to specify "axis" in above C++ TensorFlow code. I searched on web but found nothing. There is no example on web, not even in its official documentation. Please help me...

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to? Please provide the actual code you are using and any compiler errors.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] of your problem, otherwise we can't really know what's wrong.

Comment: Hello!!! Please check the question, I have modified it.